# Cannot transfer ERC-20 tokens from a contract

Tags: erc-20, transfer

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";


contract MyContract {  
    IERC20  LINK;
 
    constructor(address token) public {
             LINK = IERC20(token);
    }
    
    function transfertip(address to_, uint256 amount_) public {
       
        LINK.transfer( to_, amount_);
    }
}
```

I was able to compile and deploy the contract,but when I try to call transfer function on remix , it throws gas estimation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the contract does not have enough `LINK`. You have to pre-fund it with at least an `amount_` number of tokens if you want to be able to call `LINK.transfer` inside it.

You can transfer tokens to the smart contract by using any Ethereum wallet, e.g. [MetaMask](https://metamask.io).

Comment: yep ,it worked ,thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to hear. Don't forget to upvote my answer and mark it as accepted if it helped you.